# CodeIgniter unable to connect to Oracle 12c

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle12c

We have recently upgraded the database from Oracle 11g to 12c. However the application developed with CodeIgniter 2 throws exception upon logging in. Please see the error below:

> ERROR - 2017-07-12 16:50:35 --> Severity: Warning --> oci_connect():
>   ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
>   /system/database/drivers/oci8/oci8_driver.php 230

It look like the database driver does not support Oracle 12c. Please advise what would be solution for this issue.

Comment: Did you change the drivers to connect to 12c? Is your application in Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's in Linux. Which driver in CodeIgniter support Oracle 12c?

Comment: I didn't use the build-in driver of Codeigniter to connect with Oracle, even if i used Codeigniter for the rest of the project. I was also in Windows Server.